# Fatal authentication error while trying to connect to postgres from Java code

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When i try to connect to Postgres from bash it works well without asking for password:

```
psql -U postgres
```

When i try to connect from Java code it says:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How i am trying to connect:

```
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?autoReconnect=true", "postgres", "");
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to create a password.

Comment: Did you try `null` instead of `""` as the password?

Comment: `psql` probably uses a password [from the environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) or [the pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: But why can i then access it from bash with not password?

Comment: Adding null instead of "" did not work. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentic                                                                        ation, but no password was provided.